# mv: cannot stat 'uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm': No such file or directory

Tags: python-3.x, image, jupyter-notebook, wget, mv

```
# Downloading HorizonZero.png
!wget https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fkmiz8pQm2gJLxmNFTq74hXvaPI0zdCE/view?usp=sharing
!mv uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png
```

what is "uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png" if it is a location where the image get store then how to create new i am getting error mv: cannot stat 'uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm': No such file or directory plz help

Answer (score 0):

With `wget https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fkmiz8pQm2gJLxmNFTq74hXvaPI0zdCE/view?usp=sharing` you are downloading whats locatatet at https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fkmiz8pQm2gJLxmNFTq74hXvaPI0zdCE/view?usp=sharing
then wget saves that to a file.

with `mv uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm HorizonZero.png`

you are moving `uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm` to `HorizonZero.png`

and mv reports that `uc?id=1Djfm4PqE7Su4WqEdZKiGL-8HtrbVBuMm` is missing (in your local file system) (this may be caused by the wrong name beeing entered.)

I would advise you to run `curl -o HorizonZero.png https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Fkmiz8pQm2gJLxmNFTq74hXvaPI0zdCE/view?usp=sharing`

and check that the file is a png and not a html file redirecting to googles signin.

Or open a browser and enter the url (if needed sign in), then press Ctrl+S and save as HorizonZero.png